# Does Microsoft Edge have backward compatibility mode like IE

Tags: internet-explorer, backwards-compatibility, microsoft-edge

We are using an application that is running in IE-5 Document mode. We are downgrading the compatibility to IE-5 by using meta tag. Is this feature also works fine in Microsoft Edge?

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Edge does not have this capability. (You can still use IE on Windows 10, though.)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn384051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx